# Spring Starter Project in Eclipse -- Can not use Maven: M2E

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

```
Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 with Java JDK 1.7
```

I installed

```
Spring IDE plugin version 3.7.3
Pivotal Software Spring Tool Suite(STS 3.7.3)
```

plugins successfully, have no problem with switching to the Spring perspective and my File->new->projects has several spring related selections.

I have been building using maven with no problems.  My maven version is 3.3.3.  Checking the Help->Installation Details dialog shows eclipse m2e-workspace 0.3.1

When accessing the Eclipse Marketplace, the dialog shows Maven Integration for Eclipse(Luna and newer) 1.5 and the update button is greyed out and there is an uninstall button, so I have that installed.

When selecting Spring Starter Project, I get the creation dialog box with an error message at the top reading --

> Can not import using Maven because Can not use Maven: M2E (Eclipse
>   Maven Tooling) is not installed

I have also lost my maven sub-menu when I right click on pom.xml. Its no longer there.

Any ideas on a solution before I start removing things/changing things and possibly making things worse? Explanations also welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When installing the Spring IDE plugin into Eclipse that already has the maven plugin installed results in a serious conflict as Spring IDE also installs maven.  It may be resolvable, but I was unable to find a solution.

I did uninstall the Spring IDE, but the problem was not cleared on Eclipse restart.  I deleted the corrupted eclipse installation, while keep its workspace intact.

I finally installed STS w/eclipse and pointed it at my previous workspace.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What means "I deleted the corrupted eclipse installation"? and "installed STS w/eclipse"?? Could you be more specific? Maybe reproduce your step-by-step solution

Comment: There are two ways to work with the Spring framework.  The first is to install the plugin into an eclipse IDE version such as Luna.  The second is to install the Spring Tool Suite which is fully integrated with Eclipse and is referred to as STS.  I never put my workspace under the same directory as the Eclipse IDE directory, so I can switch IDE versions without having to worry about accidentally deleting the code.

So I simply deleted the Eclipse version from the hard drive and downloaded and installed STS.  Upon startup, I pointed it to the workspace I saved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have no idea of how to fix that.

To turnaround the this problem, I downloaded the Spring Tool Suite™ by the url: http://spring.io/tools/sts/all

This Suite have all the tools to build any Spring project that you'll want.

Hope this work for you.